# How to stop shortcut already exists message in android

Tags: android

I have code snippet for the creating shortcut icon in home page of android device.

```
private void addShortcut() {
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);     
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT;
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(flags);
    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "SPExec");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));      
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Then call it in this way:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      
        addShortcut();
}
```

**I don't want to show this message when application start.How to remove this icon duplicate message or how to mitigate icon duplication ?**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution in other posts, where they use this function, and it works fine for me

```
private void addShortcut()
{
    SharedPreferences appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Boolean isAppInstalled = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled", false);

    String currentLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
    String previousSetLanguage = appPreferences.getString("phoneLanguage", Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
    Boolean shortcutReinstall = false;
    if (!previousSetLanguage.equals(currentLanguage)) {
        shortcutReinstall = true;
    }

     if(!isAppInstalled || shortcutReinstall){

        Intent HomeScreenShortCut= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                BasicEntranceActivity.class);

        HomeScreenShortCut.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        HomeScreenShortCut.putExtra("duplicate", false);

        if(shortcutReinstall) {
            Intent removeIntent = new Intent();
            removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, HomeScreenShortCut);
            String prevAppName = appPreferences.getString("appName", getString(R.string.app_name));
            removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, prevAppName);
            removeIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"); 
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
        }

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, HomeScreenShortCut);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"); 
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);


        //Make preference true
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled", true);
        editor.putString("phoneLanguage", currentLanguage);
        editor.putString("appName", getString(R.string.app_name));
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```